# Não posso responder uma pergunta feita

Tags: suporte, perguntas-fechadas

Bom dia, eu quero saber, o porque não posso responder uma pergunta feita por um usuario, [JasperView fechando todo o sistema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/204231/65598), na que foi marcada como pendente, simplesmente porque uns usuarios não entenderam a pergunta. Eu sei qual é o problema e sei a respostas, mas simplesmente não posso responder. Estou achando chato este site.

Usuario Ronaldo Lopes, eu sei o problema q está acontecendo e é simple.

Comment: Você possui reputação suficiente para responder perguntas?

Comment: Como você sabe qual é o problema se nem o autor da pergunta sabe qual é?

Comment: @R.Santos não precisa de reputação para responder, ele não consegue responder pois a pergunta se encontra pendente. O que cabe agora é discutir se o motivo de fechamento foi correto e se existe algo que precisa ser mudado para que ela seja reaberta

Comment: @jbueno, simplesmente, porque eu tive esse erro no meu projeto

Comment: E qual é o problema?

Comment: Perguntas fechadas não podem ser respondidas até que o autor da mesma revise-a e seja reaberta. Perguntas não suficientemente claras são fechadas como tal, mas isso nem sempre quer dizer que a pergunta não esteja clara. Neste caso, por exemplo, o autor não postou o código no qual está acontecendo o problema. Por mais que você saiba resolvê-lo, há uma grande chance do seu código ser muito diferente do dele e gerar uma discussão desnecessariamente longa. A pergunta fica fechada até que o autor a revise, adicionando o código, possibilitando uma resposta que resolva diretamente o problema.

Comment: Entenda que a pergunta foi fechada porque parece não conter informações suficientes para uma resposta canônica, eu mesmo votei para fechar e não consigo me convencer que este voto foi errado. Existem regras no site e elas foram seguidas nesta pergunta assim como são seguidas em todas as outras. De qualquer forma, toda e qualquer pergunta que fica pendente pode ser reaberta se percebermos que a fechamos de modo errôneo ou se o autor da pergunta resolver editá-la para resolver o problema que foi apontado no momento do fechamento.

Comment: @Math é verdade, equivoco meu, a reputação é necessária para comentários

Comment: @jbueno, cuando se chama o metodo show(), da clase JasperReportBuider,  por default, ele vai true no EXIT_ON_CLOSED, tem q trocar

Comment: Reabri a pergunta

Comment: @Math, Obrigado

Comment: Este tipo de pergunta feito pelo Ronaldo é o tipo de pergunta que sempre vai ter coisas como *"pra mim não funcionou"*, *"deu erro"*, *"aonde eu coloco isso"*, *"meu código esta diferente"*, *"resolveu mas deu erro em outra coisa"*.

Comment: @Math Não devemos responder perguntas que não estejam bem elaboradas? Eu tenho permissão para responder, mas notei que minha resposta não está sendo bem recebida pela comunidade. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/511201/83882

Answer (score 5):

A pergunta não exibia códigos que permitia uma depuração por parte de quem nunca vivenciou o problema antes e isso provavelmente foi o motivo que levou aos usuários a marcarem como pendente.

Entretanto alguém que já tenha passado por isso antes pode estar apto a respondê-la e por isso votei para reabrí-la. Agora já pode ser respondida por qualquer usuário do site.